# removing trailing whitespace at the end of a word?

Tags: php

How do I remove a whitespace at the end of a word and not from the middle of the word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`rtrim()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php).

Manual reference: [String functions in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php