# How can I remove space at the end of string?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [removing trailing space at the end of a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476110/removing-trailing-space-at-the-end-of-a-word)

I am trying to execute a query to retrieve data but it is putting a space at the end of string and because of that it does not return any value. If I run the same query in by removing one space at the very end of the query it is executed in mqsql.

This is the query string returned by php 
select product_id from sp_url where url like '%etcenter.net
'

the space after '%etcenter.net ' is causing the problem

Comment: Could you show us your query? It would help answering.

Comment: $string = trim($string);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://php.net/trim

```
trim($variable);
```

Comment: Holy SQL Inection vulnerability batman...

Comment: Yeah, fair cop. But it's outside the scope of the question, and I get a bit bored of every sql-tagged question needing an injection disclaimer attaching.

Comment: true, however you included code.  The OP did not.  It would be better if the code you included was at least safe.  A lot of people copy-paste from here, and you're perpetuating an issue that has been plaguing the internet for decades.  Is it really that hard to change concat to a prepared statement or escape (or heck, even pseudocode)?

Comment: Not a correct answer. trim($str) also removes spaces from the start of $str. OP only wants to remove spaces from the end of the string. Use rtrim($str) instead.

Answer (score 8):

The function you are looking for is called [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/rtrim)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) command would do what you want.

For more specifics, we'd need to see the code that creates the query string.