# How to remove empty space from the end

Tags: php

My code get random line from text file:
update code:

```
<?php
$text = file_get_contents('proxy');
$textArray = explode("\n",$text);
$randArrayIndexNum = array_rand($textArray);
$randPhrase = $textArray[$randArrayIndexNum];?>
<html>
<body>

<?php
echo trim($randPhrase,"<br>");
?>

</body>
</html>
```

but random text have space on the end:

```
89.38.146.26:8080  <- here
```

How to remove it?

Comment: use `trim()` to remove spaces.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704731/how-can-i-remove-space-at-the-end-of-string

Comment: @prakash tank where i place the trim in the code please? i dont know

Comment: `<?php echo trim($randPhrase);?>` try it

Comment: @prakash tank i try but not work, i try also echo trim($randPhrase,"<br>"); but the space stay. i update the code on post

Comment: @NolaJonls : `$str = '89.38.146.26:8080  ';`
`echo trim($str); ` check this

Answer (score 0):

Use [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to remove white spaces from the beginning and the end of the string, or use [rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) to remove white spaces only from the end of the string.

Comment: where i place the trim in the code please? i dont know

Comment: yes, i check but cant get it to work. i update the code on post

Comment: From the first section of `trim`'s docs, you can see what are the options for the second argument, and `<br>` is not one of them. You can use `echo trim($text);` or `echo trim($text, "\n")` to remove only `new line` and not spaces. And where the second argument is representing a **valid** white space. For your case, just use my first example.